# How can I find the k-th smallest element of my list of random numbers?

Tags: r, random-generation

I have generated exponential random numbers using `x <- rexp(1000,1)` with `set.seed(1)`. I can look at them using `show(x)`. But how can I find the $k$-th smallest element of that list in R?

Answer (score 3):

```
> k <- 5
> sort(x)[k]
[1] 0.003897209
```